# dplyr conditionally filter on only unique items

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a dataframe with `$ID`, `$Age`, and `$Score` features. I would like filter this down to unique IDs that have a score below a specific value. For those IDs with multiple scores below the threshold, I want to only keep the oldest (i.e., maximum age).

Here's how I've tried to implement it but it is slow due to the loop. Is there a way to speed this up with dplyr or similar library?

```
#find the indexes of the items below the threshold
idx <- df$Score <= threshold
#select the below threshold rows
df <- df[idx,]
#find the unique IDs
unique_ids <- unique(df$ID)
unique_items <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=3, nrow=length(unique_ids)))
colnames(unique_items) <- colnames(df)
#loop through each unique ID
for(i in 1:length(unique_ids))
  {
    #find all the items that match that unique ID
    my.list <- df[df$ID == unique_ids[i],]
    #find the index of the oldest unique item that is below the threshold
    oldest_idx <- which.max(my.list$Age)
    #assign it the the result dataframe
    unique_items[i,] <- my.list[oldest_idx,]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also use

```
df %>%
  filter(Score < 5) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(which.min(Age))
```

Comment: Thank you. This appears to be the cleanest solution. Just for my own edification, `slice(which.min(Age))` will return the oldest (maximum) `Age` for any unique `ID`, correct?

Comment: @coolhand for each ID, it returns the row where the 'Age' is low.  If you want older, then use `which.max`

Answer (score 1):

Sample data

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(2021)
df <- tibble(ID=rep(1:2, each=5), Age=sample(10), Score=c(1:5, 3:7))
df
# # A tibble: 10 x 3
#       ID   Age Score
#    <int> <int> <int>
#  1     1     7     1
#  2     1     6     2
#  3     1     9     3
#  4     1     2     4
#  5     1     4     5
#  6     2     8     3
#  7     2    10     4
#  8     2     5     5
#  9     2     1     6
# 10     2     3     7
```

Answer:

```r
df %>%
  filter(Score < 5) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice_min(Age) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#      ID   Age Score
#   <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     2     4
# 2     2     8     3
```

Here, the min-score is 5, and the oldest age records under 5 are returned.

Comment: Thank you. The `slice_min` seemed to be what I was missing. When I run this, I get a different result for `length(unique(df$ID))` than `nrow(df)`. Shouldn't they be the same if I'm only keeping one single instance (the oldest) of each unique ID?

Comment: I don't know what data you're using or what your expected output is given that data. In my interpretation (and apparently in akrun's nearly identical answer), there do not seem to be any problems.

Comment: akrun's answer doesn't cause the same discrepancy which is why I selected it. I'll have to dig deeper into my data to understand why, but thank you for your answer

Comment: Next time, please remove the ambiguity and make it easier by including sample data and your expected output given that data. Had I known my random data did not adequately resemble your real data, I would not have attempted it.